# Firebase Storage async request with "listAll" method. React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

I'm getting an image from a user and storing it with in Cloud Storage through Firebase. The storing works fine.

Right after that I'm requesting all images from the storage to display them, but  I got the response without the last submit. So I need to refresh the page, then `useEffect` make one more request and everything works.

UPD. Here's the the complete logic:

This function is uploading image to the storage:

```
  const uploadImage =  async (image,imageName) => {
    if (image == null) return;
    const imageRef = ref(storage,`images/${imageName}`);
    try {
      uploadBytes(imageRef, image);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(`${err}`)
    }
  }
```

This function does request to firestore, but doesn't return last uploaded image every time, just randomly. sometimes it does, usually not :

```
const getImages = async () => {
  try {
    const imagesListData = await listAll(imagesListRef);
    setImagesList([]);
    imagesListData.items.forEach(item => {
      getDownloadURL(item).then(url => setImagesList(prev => [...prev,url]));
   })
  } catch(err){
    alert(err.message);
  }
}
```

after refreshing the page, useEffect does the job :

```
useEffect(() => {
  getImages();
},[])
```

As I said above sometimes it works as I expected from the first try without me changing the code(which is the most confusing),most of the times I need to refresh the page to get the last image.

p.s. list() instead listAll() give same results

Comment: not sure what the question is? You mean you upload an image and if you list it you get nothing? could you share the output as well please

Comment: Hi Frank! So let's say I currently have 2 images in my storage folder. I add one more, so there are 3 images in the storage folder. But I can not get them without refreshing the page, listAll only returns  2 references  that I had before adding.  More than that, if it's my first image and the storage is empty everything works fine, the problem starts with a second image.

Comment: Can you share the code in your `uploadImage` function?

Comment: Try using list() instead. listAll() buffers all results in memory.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the replies .  I've added the code , please check if you can help.